# Find the limit as x approaches 0 of $4/x^2$ +$2 /(1-\cos(x))$

Tags: calculus

Find the limit as x approaches 0 of $4\over x^2$ +$2 \over (1-\cos(x))$

I get stuck on the third l'Hopital where one takes the limit as x approaches 0 of $4\cos(x)-4 \over 2-2\cos(x) +4x\sin(x) +x^2\cos(x)$

I think the limit should be 0 but Wolfram alpha says it's infinity.
Is the limit 0, an integer, or infinity?

Comment: Could you fix the title ?

Comment: It would be nice to have the same limit in the title and in the question body.

Comment: The difference, rather than the sum, has a finite limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both parts blow up. On to the next question.

**Remarks:** $1.$ The limit as $x\to 0$ of  $\dfrac{4}{x^2}-\dfrac{2}{1-\cos x}$  does exist.

$2.$ As an exercise, instead of noting immediately that the limit is $\infty$ (or if you prefer, does not exist), let us use L'Hospital's Rule on the expression after it is brought to a common denominator.

So we are looking at $\dfrac{4-4cos x+2x^2}{x^2-x^2\cos x}$. It is legitimate to apply L'Hospital's Rule.

Two applications get us to $\frac{4+4\cos x}{\text{Stuff}}$. The top does not approach $0$, but the Stuff at the bottom does, so the Rule is no longer applicable.

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: limit is infinity?

Comment: Some would say infinity. Some would say does not exist.

Comment: doesn't l'hopital's rule shows that it does exist?

Comment: The Rule should not be used here.

Comment: Your remark is incorrect.

Comment: why can't the Rule be used here?

Comment: Is the rule not applicable as L'hopital  works for  infinity - infinity and not infinity + infinity?

Comment: what if you made combined the two functions so that they have the same denominator and then evaluated them? would that change the question?

Comment: You can do that. Each time that you use the Rule you need to check applicability.

Comment: I have added a brief remark about what happens with L'Hospital. The first two uses are legitimate and the third is not,

Answer (score 0):

Considering the Question in the Body

Dividing the numerator & the denominator by $1-\cos x,$

$$-\frac4{2+4\cdot\dfrac{x\sin x}{1-\cos x}+\cos x\cdot\dfrac{x^2}{1-\cos x}}$$

$$=-\frac4{2+4\cdot\dfrac{x\sin x}{1-\cos^2x}(1+\cos x)+\cos x(1+\cos x)\cdot\dfrac{x^2}{1-\cos^2 x}}$$

$$=-\frac4{2+4\cdot\dfrac x{\sin x}(1+\cos x)+\cos x(1+\cos x)\left(\dfrac x{\sin x}\right)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Do you know that $1-\cos x \sim \frac{x^2}{2}$, and hence $\frac{2}{1-\cos x} \sim \frac{4}{x^2}$ as $x\to 0$?

Answer (score 0):

By Taylor (assuming that $+$ is a typo),
$$\frac4{x^2}-\frac2{\frac12x^2-\frac1{4!}x^4+...}=\frac4{x^2}(1-(1+\frac2{4!}x^2-...))=-\frac13+o(x^2).$$
Otherwise there is no cancellation, hence $\infty$.